# How to pass object to modal dialog in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a `thymeleaf` page that shows database content (persons) in a table.

```
<tr id="tableBody">
    <td th:text="${row.id}"/>
    <td th:text="${row.firstname}"/>
    <td th:text="${row.lastname}"/>
    <td>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" th:data-row="${row}">DEL</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The last column should be a button that deletes the row. But prior, show a modal dialog with the data being deleted.

Question: how can I pass the the full row person object to a modal dialog?

I started as follows, but I'm missing how I could actually pass the person object from the clicked row *into* the modal dialog as an object (so that I can show the person fields in the modal dialog again).

The following is kind of pseudo code:

```
<div class id="editModal" ...>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-body">
       You are about to delete: <div th:text="${row.firstname}"/> <div th:text="${row.lastname}"/>

       <form action="#" th:action="@{/delete/{id}" th:object="${row}" method="delete">
          <input type="text" hidden="true" th:field="${row.id}">
       </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=${row.id})}" th:method="delete">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need a pure html+tymeleaf solution or is javascript acceptable?

Comment: I would prefer a solution pure thymeleaf, no js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure thymeleaf**

To do it in pure thymeleaf, you would need to create a dialog for every row in the table with a unique id, and open the dialog associated to the row being deleted.

Example modals:

```
<div th:each="row : ${rows}" th:attr="id=${'editModal' + row.id}">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-body">
       You are about to delete: <div th:text="${row.firstname}"/> <div th:text="${row.lastname}"/>

       <form action="#" th:action="@{/delete/{id}" th:object="${row}" method="delete">
          <input type="text" hidden="true" th:field="${row.id}">
       </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=${row.id})}" th:method="delete">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the button which opens the dialog becomes:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" th:attr="data-target=${'#editModal'+row.id}" data-row="${row}">DEL</button>
```

---

**With javascript**

If you can use javascript, I would recommend creating only a template of the modal dialog using thymeleaf, then clone it and and populate it dynamically.

Example modal:

```
<div class id="editModalTemplate">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-body">
       You are about to delete: <div data-value="firstname"/> <div data-value="lastname"/>

       <form action="#" th:action="@{/delete/_id_}" method="delete">
          <input type="text" hidden="true" name="id">
       </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id='_id_')}" th:method="delete">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The delete button:

```
<button class="btn-delete" data-id=${row.id} data-firstname="${row.firstname}" data-lastname="${row.lastname}">DEL</button>
```

Javascript (using jQuery implementation as example):

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function(){
    //clone dialog and remove ids to ensure uniqueness
    var $modal = $('#editModalTemplate').clone().removeAttr('id');

    //apply custom values where needed
    var $btn = $(this);
    var rowId = $btn.attr('data-id');
    var firstname = $btn.attr('data-firstname');
    var lastname = $btn.attr('data-lastname');

    $modal.find('[data-value="firstname"]').text(firstname );
    $modal.find('[data-value="lastname"]').text(lastname );
    $modal.find('[name="id"]').val($btn.attr('data-id'));
    $modal.find('form').attr('action').replace('_id_', rowId);     
    $modal.find('button[type="submit"]').attr('href', $modal.find('button[type="submit"]').attr('href').replace('_id_', rowId);

    //show dialog
    $modal.modal();
});
```

Comment: Could you give an alternative example using js? Probably that would involve jquery? But if the above is the only solution, I'd rather go for a js solution. I would want to show maybe 100 rows per page, so I cannot go for generating 100 hidden modal dialogs then.

Comment: @membersound I added an example with jQuery

Comment: Okay I see. But there is no way I could simply pass the full object to the modal dialog and access is using dot notation? Like `<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" th:data-row="${row}">`, and then accessing it inside the modal dialog with `th:text="{row.firstname}"`?

Comment: Because I think it's really boilerplate I have to repeat all person attributes explicit for the delete button, like `data-id=, data-firstname=, data-lastname=...`. I hoped I could just pass the full `th:data-row="{row}` object and then extract the fields in the `jquery` function?

Comment: You can't store the full object as a html attribute, but you can store it as a javascript variable `var allRows = [[${rows}]];`. This way, you only have to store id of row in html, and in jQuery you can fetch rest of data from `allRows` variable

Comment: Is there any downside of converting all `rows` to a `js` variable? I mean, would the serialization process of large lists have a negative impact?

Comment: Its much less impact than converting all `rows` to a `html block`

Answer (score 1):

The ease solution I found, hope it helps with who is struggling, the trick is to put the modal inside the same loop of the table or div, and creating and dynamic "id" with the attribute sentence of thymeleaf, like is explained in this [page](https://blog.nazrulkabir.com/2018/04/dynamic-modal-with-spring-boot-and-thymeleaf/) for an older version:

```
    <tr th:each="user: ${users}">
        <td ><a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-row="${user}"
                th:attr="data-bs-target='#modal-warning'+${user.id }">Inactivate</a> 
    
    <!--  MODAL -->
  <div th:fragment="modal" class="modal fade" th:id="modal-warning+${user.id }" tabindex="-1"
```

You could also check my original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100248/get-data-from-thymeleaf-to-a-modal-bootstrap-jquery/70107604#70107604)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30430606)

Comment: You are right, I update my answer

Comment: So actually you're creating N versions of the modal dialog? I think if you have like 100+ rows to display, this might be inefficient, even though the modals are hidden by default.

Comment: Actually no, in my case, first because the view is paginated and in other hand I'm only creating the modal if certain criteria match with "th:if" command.

Answer (score 0):

In Gustav's answer, single quotes are missing in the example for the modal window code, because of the bulky Thymeleaf code, this is important. I've been looking for a long time since there is no debugging on the HTML page.

```
<div th:fragment="modal" class="modal fade" th:id="'modalWarning'+${material.id}"  tabindex="-1">
```